# Android - httpget works on browser but not in application.(Cookies)

Tags: android, cookies, http-get

I'm want to do a HttpGet, but I got null result (but not an error). 
On app Rested when I turn on "Use User's Cookies" everything is working correctly.
How I can do that in android?